# Why facebook game request does not showing up on recipient profile?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I am implementing facebook functionality on my Android game. Registered app on facebook. Everything works normally.
But when I send request  open GameRequest dialog, select friends and send. On request I get success and request id. But on recipient side does not shows up any request or notification (On facebook desktop).

What I do wrong?

I implemented code as following. Has created requestDialog on start as document says.

```
    GameRequestContent content = new GameRequestContent.Builder().
            setTitle("Title").
            setMessage("Content").
            build();
    requestDialog.show(content);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to ask to own question.

As I was explaining above everything was implemented rightly.

[Facebook Game Request doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests) says:

*"On the `Facebook desktop site`, requests appear `as a beeper pop-up in the lower left of the screen` as well as in the `notifications jewel`. `On mobile platforms` requests will surface within the `list of notifications` in the `Facebook App`."*

**But nowhere it metioned that if you have only android app configured in Facebook it will show notifaction only on Android Facebook app not in Facebook destkop site.**

But when I looked notifiaction bar on Facebbok app then saw that game request does appear Facebook App.

Consider this not described future when developing.

I reported this issue on Facebook as Bug ([report link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1170355363046592)) and got positive feedback saying:

> You are right, that could definitely be improved. We do specify that:
>
> > **Invites that are sent by the player will appear on whatever
> >     combination of platforms supported by your game.**
>
> but only in the section "Invitable Friends API". Not very easy to
>   find.
>
> I've assigned this bug to the documentation team to state it more
>   clearly.
>
> Thanks for reporting this, Domenico

### Updated:

After days they solved problem added following sentences:

> Your implementation of requests should therefore be platform-agnostic
>   and should provide a consistent user experience, regardless of
>   platform. However, invites that are sent by the player will appear on
>   whatever combination of platforms supported by your game.

### Related other problem

Beside I want to share additional information. You can face with this problem too.
To let recipinet to open android application clicking on game request notifiaction - You have to set "Yes" option on Android application setting in facebook app as shown in image below. (This is under Android settings in facebook app).
Otherwise you will see `The requested page can not be displayed right now ...`

[image]